# How to get a horizontal line that is aligned at the bottom of a fraction?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, fractions

```
 $\frac{18e-12}{10}=\rule{5cm}{1pt}$
```

gives

[image]

How do I get something that likes this
[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Measure the expression and use `\mathpalette` in order to get the rule at the correct height.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\exprrule}[2]{%
  #1#2\mathpalette\addexprrule{#1}%
}

\newcommand{\addexprrule}[2]{%
  \sbox0{$#1#2$}%
  \rule[-\dimexpr\dp0+1pt]{5cm}{1pt}%
}

\begin{document}

$\exprrule{\frac{18e-12}{10}}{=}$
\begin{align*}
\exprrule{\frac{18e-12}{10}}{&=}
\\[1ex]
\exprrule{\frac{\dfrac{1}{5\mathstrut}}{\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{25}}}}{&=}
\\[1ex]
\exprrule{a+a}{&=}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}



\begin{document}


$\frac{18e-12}{10}=\rule{5cm}{1pt}$


$\frac{18e-12}{10}=\rule[-4pt]{5cm}{1pt}$

\end{document}
```